# Numpy's `NDArray[np.int_]` not compatible with Python's `Sequence[Integral]`?

Tags: python, numpy, mypy, python-typing, typing

Code to reproduce:

```py
from numbers import Integral
from collections.abc import Sequence

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray


def f(s: Sequence[Integral]):
    print(s)


def g() -> NDArray[np.int_]:
    return np.asarray([1, 2, 3])


def _main() -> None:
    a = g()
    f(a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _main()
```

On line 18 I get the following Mypy error:

```
Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "ndarray[Any, dtype[signedinteger[Any]]]"; expected "Sequence[Integral]"
```

What's also weird is that this error doesn't occur if I remove the  `-> None` from the `def _main() -> None`.

**EDIT**

It's even worse. Forget about `Integer` and `np.int_`. `NDArray` itself (or indeed `np.ndarray` class) seems to be incompatible with `Sequence`, which doesn't make any sense to me. Run the following code:

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray


def f(s: Sequence):
    print(s)


def g() -> np.ndarray:
    return np.asarray([1, 2, 3])


def _main() -> None:
    a = g()
    f(a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _main()
```

I get the Mypy error: `Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "ndarray[Any, Any]"; expected "Sequence[Any]"  [arg-type]`.

**EDIT AGAIN**
My versions are:

- Python 3.10.1
- Mypy 1.0.1
- Numpy 1.24.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `NDArray[T]` is considered neither a **nominal** nor a **structural** [subtype](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) of `Sequence[T]`.

The first is easily explained: `np.ndarray` does not inherit from `collections.abc.Sequence`. Therefore it is not a nominal subtype of it.

The second actually took me a bit of digging, but the underlying issue is that the stubs for the `Sequence` type **do not define it as a protocol**. While it is common to talk about the "sequence protocol", there is technically no built-in protocol class for it.

This is in contrast to something like `Iterable` for example. That is indeed defined as a protocol, which means that any class (no matter its inheritance) that implements the corresponding `__iter__` method will be treated as a structural subtype of `Iterable` by type checkers.

See the typeshed source for [`Iterable`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/806b13435ceadbf6aba407bcfeb9198fc919ae3e/stdlib/typing.pyi#L348) vs. that for [`Sequence`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/806b13435ceadbf6aba407bcfeb9198fc919ae3e/stdlib/typing.pyi#L467). A protocol [must have](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#merging-and-extending-protocols) `typing.Protocol` as one of its immediate base classes. As to *why* something like `Sequence` is not made an actual protocol, I found no clear explanation. I found a brief mention in response to [this comment](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8345#issuecomment-580451138), but no real reasons given.

If we change your example for `f` to take an `Iterable`, it will be recognized by `mypy` as a supertype of `NDArray`:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from numbers import Integral

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray


def f(s: Iterable[Integral]) -> None:
    print(s)


def g() -> NDArray[np.int_]:
    return np.asarray([1, 2, 3])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f(g())
```

However this brings us to a tangentially related problem. In terms of actual **usefulness** you might as well ditch the `numbers.Integral` here because even using `Iterable[str]` would not cause an error, if we passed `NDArray[np.int_]` to it.

This is due to the fact that [`ndarray.__iter__`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.25.0.dev0/numpy/__init__.pyi#L1843) is typed as returning [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any), which means all bets are off and *any* `ndarray` will match literally *any* iterable. Why that is the case is again something better to be discussed with the developers.

You should just be aware that no checks for the item type will ever fail, if you rely on the `Iterable` protocol for numpy arrays.

If you really want to have an "actual" sequence-like protocol, you'll need to write one yourself, but I fear this might become difficult for this use case because the numpy type annotations are not trivial and (as far as I know) not comprehensive at all.

Comment: Aaaah, don't you just **love** Python? LOL. (Thank you very much for your very in-depth research and answer by the way.)

Comment: I do, actually. :) Despite its flaws, of which there are many. Glad I could help.